# how to create a program that inputs a sentence and then displays each word of the sentence on a separate line in python

Tags: python

how to create a program that inputs a sentence and then displays each word of the sentence on a separate line

I have tried using the split function but instead it displays the words on the same line, in a list.

here is my code:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence:")
print(sentence.split(" "))
```

Comment: `split` returns a list. iterate over each element of the list and print it. by default print adds a new line after each call.

Comment: ``s.replace(" ", "\n")`` or ``"\n".join(s.split(" "))``

Comment: As an aside, the `" "` separator is redundant in this example

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence:") 
for item in sentence.split(" "):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sep keyword argument:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence:")
print(*sentence.split(" "), sep='\n')
```

Outputs:

```
Enter a sentence: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
```

Answer (score 0):

split creates a list. You might want to iterate over that list and print the word one by one

```py
sentence = input("Enter a sentence:")
words = sentence.split(" ")
for word in words:
    print(word)
```